# show relational data in view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make a blog. 
I want to be able to post blogs and other people must be able to comment on those blogs. To achieve this I have made two models Messages and Comments. with a one to many relationship with the idea in mind that I could acces both models from my view. I use entity framework with codefirst workflow. Now I am stuck on the view with reading the relational data from the Comments model with this error message:

> 'IEnumerable ' does not contain a 'Comments' definition and no 'Comments' extension method that accepts an initial 'IEnumerable ' type of argument can be found (do you miss a usage or assembly reference?)

(this error is translated so excuse me if I've translated something wrong)

I have read some questions on stackoverflow about this error but I did'nt realy understand everything because I'am pretty new to C# and asp.net mvc

**Here are my models**

```
namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Messages
    {
        public int MessagesId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }

        public Messages()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Comments
    {
        public int CommentsId { get; set; }
        public string Comments_body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual Messages Messages { get; set; }

        public Comments()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my controller**

```
    public class MessagesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MessagesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            var message = _context.messages.Include(m => 
            m.Comments).ToList();

            return View(message);
        }
   }
```

**And here is my view**

```
@model IEnumerable <Portfolio.Models.Messages>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blog";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                @foreach (var messages in Model)
                {
                    <div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    @*Gets the title of the blog post*@
                                    <h2 class="panel-title">
                                    @messages.Title</h2>
                                    @messages.WhenCreated
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
           @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                  id="@messages.MessagesId" onclick="ShowComments(this.id)">
                        Show Comments
                        </button>

@*this is the container where al the comments are placed in and where you 
can post comments*@
                        <div class="hidden" id="Comm@(messages.MessagesId)">
                            <div class="row" id="CommentContainer">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h3>Post Comment</h3>
                                    @*The form to post comments*@
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", 
                                    "Messages"))
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Comment</label>
                                            @Html.TextArea("editor", 
                                     htmlAttributes: new { name = "editor1",             
                                  id ="editor", rows = "10", cols = "180" })
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn 
                                        btn-primary" id="PostButton">
                                        Post Comment</button>
                                    }

                                    @*CKEdito script*@
                                    <script>
                                        CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
                                    </script>


                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @foreach (var comments in 
                                             Model.Comments)
                                            {
                                                if (comments.CommentsId == 
                                                    messages.MessagesId)
                                                {
                                                    <div class="well" 
                                                     id="CommentBox">

                                              <h7>@comments.WhenCreated</h7>

     @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(comments.Comments_body))
                                                    </div>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <h2>Be the first to 
                                                    react!</h2>
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                        id="@messages.MessagesId" 
                        onclick="HideComments(this.id)">
                        Hide Comments</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error originates from this part in the view

> @foreach (var comments in Model.Comments)
>    {

So im not entirely sure if I just call it wrong in my view or that something is wrong in my controller or model.

Comment: You need nested `foreach` loops - `@foreach (var messages in Model) { .... foreach (var comments in messages.Comments) { .... } }`

Comment: Just clarifying, `@foreach (var comments in Model.Comments) {` should be `@foreach (var comments in messages.Comments) {`

Comment: alright thnx im going to try it right away

Comment: I have tried that but now I get this error ( A local or parameter named 'messages' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter) Is this because it is called before?

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Muecke and @Callum Linington said. The foreach loop should be nested like this.

```
@foreach (var message in Model)
{
    foreach (var comments in message.Comments)
    {
    }
{
```

where I have changed var messages to message because that local variable already existed.

Comment: But that is only the start of your problems. You have invalid html everywhere (duplicate `id` attributes). You have forms that will not do anything meaningful (you wont even know which message the new comment is associated with)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I know but I was not jet working on that I first wanted to solve this problem and then I could work on those problems. And those problems werent my question. And yes there are forms that not jet do anything because it is still work in progress. But thnx for the headsup xD That duplicate Id is something I missed so thanks for that.